# Long arithmetics

Tags: delete-file

Do something with it guys

They ask to add something
because it looks like my post is mostly code.
I hope it's enough.

There's no way to delete it.

```
    Solong sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        if ((i != 0) && (i != 8)) {
            sum = sum + n2[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << sum;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You're using a fixed size array to hold your numbers.  What happens when you have more than 1000 digits in your number?

Comment: Which input caused the issue? Without it, your question is incomplete. However, hardcode the input instead to get closer to the required minimal example.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt every digit I typed it does not work on.

Comment: Well, then it should be trivial to adjust your code. Why should any reader have to guess what you might have considered proper input? *You* are supposed to supply that info!

Answer (score 3):

These are the problems that punched me in the face looking at your code -- so I might have missed a few less obvious things.

`operator = (const int & b)`, ignores the argument's value and just makes the low-order word zero.  So I'm thinking you want `number[0] = b;`.  You also need to update `size`.  You should also probably take care of the case when b overflows your radix, setting `size` and populating higer-order words.

In `operator +`, a radix digit overflow is detected and the carry flag is set, but the result's digit is never reduced by the value represented by the carry to the next digit:

```
if (res.number[i] >= res.radix) {
    overDecimal = 1;
}
```

So this needs something like `res.number[i] -= res.radix`
Also, high-order words beyond its `size` are used when one argument has a smaller `size` than the other.  The assignment operators do not bother to make sure that their high-order words, above `size` are set to zero, so you either need to make sure they are set to zero everywhere else, or ignore these non-zero high-order words in this function.

In the loop in `void operator <<`, your index `i` starts at the last element, but is updated by incrementing:

```
    for (int i=a.size-1; ...; ++i) { ...
```

So I'm guessing this needs to be changed to `--i`

Some other problems:

Both `operator = (...` should return `Solong&` instead of `void`, with `return *this;` at the end.

`operator << (std::ostream& out, const Solong &a)` should return `std::ostream&` instead of `void`, with `return out;` at the end.

Comment: The condition itself is dangerous too: if `a.number[a.size-1]==0` then the loop will go forever (until it segfaults or something).

Comment: @Chris That conditional expression made my mind hurt, so I am trying not to think about it, but I strongly suspect what you say is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your program caused a segmentation fault in this function:

```
  > void operator << (std::ostream& out, const Solong &a) {
  >     for (int i = a.size - 1; i != -1 || (i != a.size - 1 && a.number[a.size - 1] == 0); ++i) {
x >        out << a.number[i];
  >     }
  > }
```

You can find this line by using a debugger. On linux you may want to use `gdb`. If you are using some IDE, it should be integrated there. I'm not sure what you want to do in this function. Maybe you could just write this?

```
for (int i = a.size - 1; i >= 0; --i) out << a.number[i];
```

The program dosen't crash anymore after changing this. I got `-1087373312` as result for `42` but you have undefined behavior in your application. I get another result each time I run it. Now I will show some other things I would change. It did work for me after doing this:

---

I would use std::vector to store the numbers. This container would hold the size for you and you can change it by using `resize`:

```
class Solong {
private:
    int radix = 10;
    std::vector<int> number;
```

I have to change the constructor then:

```
public:
    Solong() :
        number(1, 1) // are you shure you want initialize it with 1 instead of 0?
    {}
```

You may also want to have a constructor to set the initial value.

```
    Solong(const int &value)
    {
        *this = value;
    }
```

The `operator<<` sould return a reference to `out`:

```
    friend Solong operator+ (const Solong &a, const Solong &b);
    friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Solong &a);
```

Since I'm not using an array in this class anymore, I can use the implicit definition of `operator=(const Solong &b)`. I would just remove the custom definition of `operator=(const Solong &b)` from the class.

I think you want to assign `b` to `number` instead of `0` in the function `operator=(const int &b)`. You should return a reference to the object itself as well. Since you only allow *0-9* per `int`, you have to ensure this, too.

```
    void operator= (int b) {
        this->number.clear();
        while (b > 0) {
            this->number.push_back(b % radix);
            b = b / radix;
        }
    }
};
```

For `operator+` there are multiple things:

- I have to use `resize` of `number` now.
- If you want to put the definition in a header file, you have to specify `inline`.
- The condition `|| overDecimal` seems wrong to me, since they can cause a segmentation fault.
- You have to check if `a.number[i]` and `b.number[i]` is valid before reading this value.
- And you should change res.number[i] if there is an overflow

Here is my updated implementation:

```
inline Solong operator+ (const Solong &a, const Solong &b) {
    Solong res;
    res.number.resize(std::max(a.number.size(), b.number.size()));
    int overDecimal = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < res.number.size(); ++i) {
        int aDigit = (a.number.size() > i ? a.number[i] : 0);
        int bDigit = (b.number.size() > i ? b.number[i] : 0);
        res.number[i] = aDigit + bDigit + overDecimal;
        overDecimal = 0;
        if (res.number[i] >= res.radix) {
            overDecimal = 1;
            res.number[i] = res.number[i] % res.radix;
        }
    }
    if (overDecimal)
        res.number.push_back(overDecimal);
    return res;
}
```

Finally I fixed `operator<<` just like written above, added the keyword `inline` and return a reference to `out`:

```
inline std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const &a) {
    for (int i = a.number.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        out << a.number[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

I would also change `i` to `std::size_t` and use the whole size of `int` for one digit. Not just 10 values per `int`. I would then changed the name of `overDecimal` to `overflowedDigit` of cource since there would be no *decimalism* anymore. You should also consider that you are not supporting negative numbers right now. But all this would add some complexity and I don't want descripe it now.